# useEffect infinite loop with axios

Tags: javascript, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm stuck in an infinite loop in useEffect despite having tried the clean up function

I tried to pass [] and [usersDB] as the 2nd parameter of useEffect and it didn't work because [] makes it run only one time and it's not the behavior I'm looking for (I want it to run after each update)

```
 const ListUsers = () => {
  const [usersDB, setUsersDB] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = async () => {
      const response = await axios
        .get("http://localhost:4000/contacts")
        .catch((error) => console.log(error.resp));
      setUsersDB(response.data);
    };
    getUsers();
  }); 

  console.log(usersDB);

  return (
    <div>
        <div>
          {usersDB.map((user, index) => (
            <CardUsers key={user._id} user={user} />
          ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListUsers;
```

Comment: You "want it to run after each update" of what?

Comment: You're explaining the problem, yet not exactly the desired behaviour ;)

Comment: Put an empty array as the second argument of useEffect(()=> {}, [])
Checkout the [React Js Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Answer (score 1):

Every time the component renders, it runs your `useEffect`.  Your `useEffect` calls `setUsersDB`, which updates state, which causes a rerender, which runs `useEffect`...

You can add an array of values at the end of `useEffect` which tells the `useEffect` to only run if any of the included values have changed.  But if you add an empty array, it tells the `useEffect` to run only once, and never again, as there are no values that it depends on that have changed.  You mention that you tried this, and that you want `useEffect` to run after each update.  Each update of what?  If there is some other value that is being updated elsewhere, and you want `useEffect` to be dependent on that value, then stick it in the dependency array.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = async () => {
      const response = await axios
        .get("http://localhost:4000/contacts")
        .catch((error) => console.log(error.resp));
      setUsersDB(response.data);
    };
    getUsers();
  }, [some updating value])
```

Comment: My application is simple, it does operation CRUD(create,read,update,delete) on a database and after each operation I want it to load the database only once to refresh data on frontend and not to enter an infinite loop.
I tried clean-up techniques on useEffect and it didn't work.

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code. How are you accomplishing the CRUD operations?  Where is that happening relative to your `ListUsers` component?  In the parent?  Part of each CRUD operation will need to involve updating some placeholder variable, which can be passed to `ListUsers` as a prop, and then used in the `useeffect` dependency array.